# Warp terminal isnt loading p10k theme from zsh

Tags: terminal, zsh, zshrc, warp, warp10

I have an issue with my Warp terminal. I have iTerm2 configured with zsh and the powerlevel10k theme, and it's perfect and well set up. However, I'd like to know how to transfer this configuration to the Warp terminal. I can only load the configuration style into Warp when I run the command: 'exec zsh.' But I'd prefer it to load this terminal style without needing to run this command every time I open Warp.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

warp / iterm2

[image]

[image]

I don't want to have to run the command: exec zsh every time to load the theme. I've also tried configuring the p10 directly from Warp, but it still doesn't pick up the configuration theme

Comment: I don't know Warp, but if you explicitly need to do an `exec zsh` to make it work, I would conclude that your Warp does **not** run an (interactive) zsh on its own. Hence I would first analyze what shell Warp is loading: A non-interactive zsh (possible, but unlikely), a zsh with startup files disabled, or a shell which is different from zsh?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to explicitly instruct Warp to honor your prompt preferences. Go to *Settings* > *Appearance* > *Prompt* and select *Shell prompt (PS1)*.

Keep in mind that Warp is unable to put the command line editor on the last line of the prompt, as it always creates an additional new line for that. This means that your two-line prompt will have an essentially empty second line in Warp. It's a good idea to use a one-line prompt with Warp. You can switch by running `p10k configure`.

Also note that subshells in Warp do not get instrumented, so if you run `exec zsh` or just `zsh` in Warp, you'll lose Warp-specific features. This explains why `exec zsh` gave you the usual zsh prompt you are accustomed to -- this command practically turned Warp into a regular terminal not unlike iTerm2.

Lastly, if your prompt renders funny in Warp, try setting *Enforce minimum contrast* to *Never* in *Settings* under *Appearance*.